# Azure Automation: Powershell 5.1 Runbook: Resume-AzSynapseSqlPool : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-synapse, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm very new to PowerShell. This was my first PS script ever. Thanks for helping this newb.

I created a Powershell 5.1 in a scheduled runbook that pauses/resumes dedicated SQLPools on a schedule. It has been working great until yesterday and today. Both scheduled Resume commands timed out. On 2 days 8/30 and 8/31 the Resume command hung for an hour and then errored out. I am not sure the cause.

This is the error log:

```
Resume-AzSynapseSqlPool : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'The operation timed out and automatically rolled back. Please retry the operation.' At line:202 char:9 + Resume-AzSynapseSqlPool -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName –Name ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Resume-AzSynapseSqlPool], CloudException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Synapse.ResumeAzureSynapseSqlPool
```

Do you suggest this be put into a try/catch? It is currently in an if/else.

Please advise how best to cope with this issue.

UPDATE: 9/25 4pm; additional odd runbook behavior. Yesterday, my scheduled runbook generated this result with 9 errors. It just randomly failed. It ran fine again at 7pm and then today at 7:55am
[image]

all 9 errors similar to:

```
Get-AzContext : The 'Get-AzContext' command was found in the module 'Az.Accounts', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Accounts'. At line:45 char:1 + Get-AzContext -ListAvailable + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzContext:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

Suggestions for how to debug, or error catch this seemingly random behavior? Or, is this just the status-quo for Azure Automation performance??

I have not written any of my code to be within a try/catch. Would this help?

```
try
{
   
}
catch {
   
}
```